# Number is between two columns of a data frame

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 1, 5), c(12, 8, 5, 11))
names(df) <- c('x', 'y')
df

  x  y
1 1 12
2 2  8
3 1  5
4 5 11
```

I have a number, say `11`. For each row, I would like a vector which is generated such that if `x <= 11 <= y`, `TRUE` is outputted. In this case,

```
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

is the desired output.

There is an obvious way to do this: loops. But as far as I know, people who are good at `R` hate `for` loops. Is there a way doing this without using `for`? I was thinking about perhaps using `apply`, but I don't know how to incorpoate the double inequality for the `FUN` argument.

Comment: You need the `&` operator i.e. `with(df, x <=11  & 11<=y)`
`

Comment: @akrun Thank you, feel free to post that as an answer and I can award points! I'm not very familiar with `with`, which was the issue here.

Comment: @Clarinetist  It's okay.  You can post that as answer with some explanations.

Comment: I guess it should be **>=** in the second position (x <= 11 <= y), so we have `df$x <= 11 & df$y >= 11`.

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar not sure why you'd use `ifelse` for that.... `ifelse({...}, TRUE, FALSE)` is equivalent to `{...}`, just less efficient computationally and more typing. And using strings `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` rather than the actual logical values `TRUE` and `FALSE` is just asking for confusion.

Comment: yes thanks @Gregor you are right..

Answer (score 0):

Use logical AND operator (&) to check both conditions simultaneously

```
(df$x<=11) & (df$y>=11)
```

Comment: This was posted like an hour ago in comments.